# Why am I getting "Unable to update database to match the current model ..."

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using code-first migrations and am trying to solve a problem as I attempt to automate my database deployment.

I have a model like

```
public abstract class MyModel
{
    // ... 

    public bool MyBooleanColumn { get; set; }
}
```

and I expect the generated column in SQL Server to be `BIT NOT NULL`.

Because some old migration, say `2013030378749_SomeOldMigrations.cs`, that I think was manually written, is wrong, this column ends up as `BIT NULL` when I generated a new database from scratch via `Update-Database` command.

I'm trying to retroactively fix it. So I write a new migration `2018031519731_RetroactivelyFixThings.cs` and in it put

```
public override void Up()
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.MyModel", "MyBooleanColumn", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
}
```

but after that is applied I get the `"Unable to update database to match the current model ..."` exception. I verify that the change was made to column, and my model wasn't change. So what's going on here?

Comment: Have you already tried to remove this new migration and then run then command update-database without it? If it works, then you know your database at this point it matching your model. If it has gives you an error, your database is already not matching your model.

Comment: When you say "I write a new migration ...", you mean you used the add-migration command, right?